# How to import recovered databases into new TFS 2008 SP1 instance

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008

We recently had our TFS 2008 (non-SP1) server crash.  I installed a new instance of TFS 2008 SP1 onto Windows 2008 and SQL 2008.  The original installation was Windows 2003 and SQL 2005.  I had to "slipstream" (i believe is thats what its called) the Service Pack into the actual Setup package.  I have a new instance up and running, but do not see an easy way to import the projects fromt he old databases.

Our original machine had a raid failure and I had to use raid reconstructor to recover the data.  Our backups were not good apparently so I only have the recovered MDF/LDF's from the raid reconstructor.  With alot of DBCC fixing to the databases I have them now online and I can query data.

Is it possible to import the projects, files, history and workitems into the new instance?

I tried replacing the new instance with these databases and followed all the online instructions but i came to a deadend when everything i did said the data access was not compatible.  I am assuming because of my new install was SP1 and the original db's were NOT SP1.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Because you might have two options to restore your TFS system:

1. Get into a compatible mode, so roll-back your TFS installation to exclude SP1.
2. Install a TFS 2010 system, and approach this as a migration from 2008 to 2010. I think the online descriptions for such a migration suggest that the 2010 installation will recognize a 2008 database and start migrating it to 2010.

But ... my gutt feeling says there is something wrong with the database structure or content after restore. What system is actually telling you the data access is not compatible?